# Google Apps Script UIApp : no way to create a clickable row in a dashboard tableChart?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am a beginner in programming and I made a dashboard (populated by a spreadsheet) with Google Apps Script UIApp for my Google Apps website but I can't find the way  to create a clickable row in the tableChart (I would like to open a link to a shared document previously stored in the Drive by clicking on each row). It seems impossible to use the Google Visualization APi in this UiApp. I tried to create a Handler but i was not able to link it with the tableChart...Am I wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please edit your question to include some code detailing what you have tried, or we will not be able to help you very well at all!

Answer (score 0):

Charts are used to display data, not to create interactive UI elements. You may want to look into using UiApp's [FlexTable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_flextable) class to accomplish your goal.